# I am getting error "command \bibname unspecified" while compiling a latex document in R markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, overleaf, tinytex

I am trying to create an R Markdown Template on the basis of a LaTeX template I found on Overleaf. The template preamble uses many packages. I am trying to compile this latex file in RStudio using tinytex latex compiler, and during this process, I am getting error "Latex Error: Command \bibname unspecified. I am attaching both, the preamble from overleaf, and the YAML specification from R Markdown.

Overleaf Preamble

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report} %[twoside, 14pt]

% ==== MY BUNCH OF PACKAGES ====

\usepackage[a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bindingoffset=5mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
%\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\newcommand\quoteref[1]{\csname#1\endcsname}%
\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{changepage}   % for the adjust width environment
\usepackage{setspace}

% ----------- code environment settings
\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}
 
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,                  
    tabsize=2
}
\lstset{style=mystyle}

% ---------------- chapter abstracts
\newenvironment{chapabstract}
{
\begin{center}
    \noindent\makebox[0.8\linewidth]{\rule{0.8\paperwidth}{0.4pt}}
\end{center}
\vspace{2mm}
\list{}{
\setlength{\leftmargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\rightmargin}{\leftmargin}
}
\item\relax
}
{\par}
\makeatother

% ------------- hyperref
%\biboptions{authoryear,square,sort&compress}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}

% -------------- journals shortcuts 
\newcommand{\aaa}{Anonymous Ambiguous Abstracts}
\newcommand{\bbb}{Boring Bibliographic Book}

% ----------- glossary entries for summary of acronyms
\makenoidxglossaries
\newglossaryentry{AAA}{name=AAA, description={Ambitious Amicable Ants}}
\newglossaryentry{BBB}{name=BBBB, description={Babbling Bumbling Band of Baboons}}
\newglossaryentry{CCC}{name=CCC, description={Condescending Critical Cucumber}}
\newglossaryentry{BFG}{name=BFG, description={Big Friendly Giant}}

% ==== TEMPLATE PACKAGES ====

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{lipsum}         % fill with latin nonsense
```

YAML Specification in R Markdown

```
title: "Ambra2"
author: "Maulik Bhatt"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: 
    bookdown::pdf_document2:
        template: Ambra.tex
        keep_tex: true
Bibliography: references.bib
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you share "Ambra.tex"?

Comment: The tex file can be viewed at https://www.overleaf.com/read/dtvsbhspmbth